# How do I assign a count to a new column, counting the rows in a groupby when the current row doesn't belong in the group being counted?

Tags: python, pandas, transactions

In python I would like to modify a dataset. I have a transaction based data set as per the code below:

```
data = {
'TRANSACTIONDATETIME': ['1-Jan-23', '2-Jan-23', '3-Jan-23', '4-Jan-23', '4-Jan-23', '5-Jan-23', '2-Jan-23', '3-Jan-23', '8-Jan-23', '9-Jan-23'],
'CARD_NUM': [123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 234, 234, 234, 234],
'WINDOW': [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 4, 4],
'COUNT_CURRENT_WINDOW': [1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2]}
```

WINDOW groups the transactions on each card by 48 hours. E.g. A transaction is attributed  WINDOW = 1 if it falls in the  the first 48 hours of transactions (i.e. the first transaction on a card is always WINDOW=1). WINDOW = 2 will include transactions in the second 48 hours (relative to the first transaction on that card).

COUNT_CURRENT_WINDOW is a cumulative count of transactions occuring in the current row's WINDOW group.

Using pandas (and preferably without loops), I'd like to code 3 new columns that display what the count of transactions was in the previous 3 WINDOW groups per card. I.e.

COUNT_PREV_WINDOW = total count of transactions on the card occuring in (current row's (WINDOW value) minus 1
COUNT_ 2WINDOWS_AGO = total count of transactions on the card occuring in (current row's WINDOW value) minus 2
COUNT_3WINDOWS_AGO =  total count of transactions on the card occuring in (current row's WINDOW value) minus 3

There will be occasions where there were no transactions in the previous WINDOW group. E.g. When the current row's WINDOW =1. Another example is if the current row's WINDOW = 4 but no transactions have occured since WINDOW = 1. The desired output below demonstrates this for card=234).

The desired output should looks like the following with no changes to sorting:

```
data = {
'TRANSACTIONDATETIME': ['1-Jan-23', '2-Jan-23', '3-Jan-23', '4-Jan-23', '4-Jan-23', '5-Jan-23', '2-Jan-23', '3-Jan-23', '8-Jan-23', '9-Jan-23'],
'CARD_NUM': [123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 234, 234, 234, 234],
'WINDOW': [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 4, 4],
'COUNT_CURRENT_WINDOW': [1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2],
'COUNT_PREV_WINDOW ': [0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0],
'COUNT_2WINDOWS_AGO ': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0],
'COUNT_3WINDOWS_AGO': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2]}
```

I would prefer not to use loops due to efficiency as it as the real dataset is very large.

I have tried the following and similar variations but it just counts the current group and outputs the max.:

```
df['COUNT_PREV_WINDOW'] = df.groupby(['CARD_NUM',df['WINDOW']-1])['COUNT_CURRENT_WINDOW'].max().fillna(0)
```

Comment: "*I would prefer not to use loops due to efficiency*" -> in this particular case a loop will not be less efficient, in fact using several `assign` is identical to using a loop except it's not flexible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code**

```
df1 = (pd.crosstab(df['CARD_NUM'], df['WINDOW'])
         .stack().groupby(level=0).shift(1).fillna(0).astype('int')
         .reset_index(name='COUNT_PREV_WINDOW')
         .assign(COUNT_2WINDOWS_AGO=lambda x: x['COUNT_PREV_WINDOW'].groupby(x['CARD_NUM']).shift(1).fillna(0).astype('int'))
         .assign(COUNT_3WINDOWS_AGO=lambda x: x['COUNT_PREV_WINDOW'].groupby(x['CARD_NUM']).shift(2).fillna(0).astype('int')))
```

`df1`

```
CARD_NUM    WINDOW  COUNT_PREV_WINDOW   COUNT_2WINDOWS_AGO  COUNT_3WINDOWS_AGO
0   123     1       0                   0                   0
1   123     2       2                   0                   0
2   123     3       3                   2                   0
3   123     4       1                   3                   2
4   234     1       0                   0                   0
5   234     2       2                   0                   0
6   234     3       0                   2                   0
7   234     4       0                   0                   2
```

merge df and df1

```
out = df.merge(df1, how='left')
```

`out`(image)

[image: out]

I also don't want to attach the output as image, but your column names are too long. It's inconvenient even when solve problem, please keep it brief from next time.

Comment: This works beautifully and is very lite. Noted re: column names. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a mapping DataFrame and [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) in a loop:

```
N_DAYS = 3

tmp = (df.groupby(['CARD_NUM', 'WINDOW'], as_index=False)
       ['COUNT_CURRENT_WINDOW'].size()
      )

for i in range(N_DAYS):
    df[f'COUNT_{i+1}WINDOWS_AGO' if i else 'COUNT_PREV_WINDOW'] = (
        df.merge(tmp.eval(f'WINDOW = WINDOW+{i+1}'),
                 on=['CARD_NUM', 'WINDOW'], how='left')
        ['size'].fillna(0, downcast='infer')
    )
```

Output:

```
  TRANSACTIONDATETIME  CARD_NUM  WINDOW  COUNT_CURRENT_WINDOW  COUNT_PREV_WINDOW  COUNT_2WINDOWS_AGO  COUNT_3WINDOWS_AGO
0            1-Jan-23       123       1                     1                  0                   0                   0
1            2-Jan-23       123       1                     2                  0                   0                   0
2            3-Jan-23       123       2                     1                  2                   0                   0
3            4-Jan-23       123       2                     2                  2                   0                   0
4            4-Jan-23       123       2                     3                  2                   0                   0
5            5-Jan-23       123       3                     1                  3                   2                   0
6            2-Jan-23       234       1                     1                  0                   0                   0
7            3-Jan-23       234       1                     2                  0                   0                   0
8            8-Jan-23       234       4                     1                  0                   0                   2
9            9-Jan-23       234       4                     2                  0                   0                   2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `Series.shift`:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {
'TRANSACTIONDATETIME': ['1-Jan-23', '2-Jan-23', '3-Jan-23', '4-Jan-23', '4-Jan-23', '5-Jan-23', '2-Jan-23', '3-Jan-23', '8-Jan-23', '9-Jan-23'],
'CARD_NUM': [123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 234, 234, 234, 234],
'WINDOW': [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 4, 4],
'COUNT_CURRENT_WINDOW': [1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
for i in range(1,4):
    df = pd.merge(df, df.groupby(['CARD_NUM', 'WINDOW']).count()['TRANSACTIONDATETIME'].shift(i).fillna(0).rename(f'COUNT_PREV_{i}_WINDOW'), left_on=['CARD_NUM', 'WINDOW'], right_index=True)
df
```

This results in:

```
  TRANSACTIONDATETIME  CARD_NUM  WINDOW  COUNT_CURRENT_WINDOW   
0            1-Jan-23       123       1                     1  \
1            2-Jan-23       123       1                     2   
2            3-Jan-23       123       2                     1   
3            4-Jan-23       123       2                     2   
4            4-Jan-23       123       2                     3   
5            5-Jan-23       123       3                     1   
6            2-Jan-23       234       1                     1   
7            3-Jan-23       234       1                     2   
8            8-Jan-23       234       4                     1   
9            9-Jan-23       234       4                     2   

   COUNT_PREV_1_WINDOW  COUNT_PREV_2_WINDOW  COUNT_PREV_3_WINDOW  
0                  0.0                  0.0                  0.0  
1                  0.0                  0.0                  0.0  
2                  2.0                  0.0                  0.0  
3                  2.0                  0.0                  0.0  
4                  2.0                  0.0                  0.0  
5                  3.0                  2.0                  0.0  
6                  1.0                  3.0                  2.0  
7                  1.0                  3.0                  2.0  
8                  2.0                  1.0                  3.0  
9                  2.0                  1.0                  3.0
```

Comment: Ah sorry, I just saw, that there might be missing windows in the data. In that case you could create dummy entries for the missing windows, so that the `shift` command takes those into account. I will update my answer.